# User-defined conversion operator template and built-in operators: no match for operator

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider the following MCVE.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,int>::value,int>::type = 0>
    operator T() const { return static_cast<T>(1); }
};

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    A a;
    return x + a;
}
```

**clang** compiles it fine. [**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/g/6V5Zc3)

But **GCC** fails with:

```
error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'int' and 'A')
  return x + a;
         ~~^~~
```

**Question:** who is right and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe clang is right.

To do lookup on `+`, since at least one argument has class type, we consider [member, non-member, and builtin candidates](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/over#match.oper-6). There aren't any member or non-member candidates, so that's eay enough. There is a builtin candidate for [`int operator+(int, int)`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/over.built#12), which is the only candidate. That candidate is viable because `A` can be convertible to `int`, directly (we have a standard conversion from `A` to `const A&` for the implicit object parameter, and then the user defined conversion from that to `int`, there's no further conversion necessary). As we have one viable candidate, that trivially makes it the best viable candidate.

---

Note that if `A` just had `operator int() const { return 1; }`, gcc would accept it. It's just the conversion function *template* that fails to be considered.